# Programmatically finding an Excel file's Excel version

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I'm using an OleDbConnection to connect to a spreadsheet from a C# program.  One of the parameters in the connection string is the Excel version.

*"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties="**Excel 8.0**;HDR=YES"*

Given the path of an Excel file how can I find out which Excel format version it uses?

Thanks in advance,

T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [OLE File Property Reader](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9BA6FAC6-520B-4A0A-878A-53EC8300C4C2&displaylang=en). Register dsofile.dll with regsvr32 and add it as a reference in your application. The following code will output the type of Excel file. It will not work on xlsx/docx since those are not OLE compunds object files, but should work on all older Office formats (2007/2003/XP).

```
var doc = new OleDocumentPropertiesClass();            
doc.Open(@"c:\spreadhseet.xls", false, dsoFileOpenOptions.dsoOptionDefault);
Console.WriteLine(doc.OleDocumentType);
```

Answer (score 3):

I addition to what was said and apart from using Excel automation to open the file you can try reading file version from your code:

**xls** files: those are saved as [structured storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380369(VS.85).aspx). you can use the technique from the article here: [How To Determine Which Version of Excel Wrote a Workbook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225029)

**xlsx** files: you can open them as zip files. Version is in app.xml file AppVersion field.